# Security token in salesforce

Tags: salesforce-lightning

I am interested in using the Salesforce API to obtain some ticket information, but I need to retrieve the security token from my Salesforce account first. According to the method I found, I need to reset my security token in my account settings, and a new token will be sent to me by email.

However, I am concerned about whether resetting the security token will affect my account access and result in the loss of my ticketing history. Can you please advise on this matter?

Thank you in advance.